# Dual NIC - similar IP but different networks

Tags: ip, network-printer, ipv4

I have two NICs installed in a PC.  Both have a static IP.  Business Network is 192.168.1.173, and Control Network is 192.168.1.75.

I need to access a network printer at 192.168.1.63 (which is on the business network).  If I unplug the control network and reboot - it works.  With the control network connected - it does not.  If it try to access via a web browser 192.168.1.63, it pulls up a PLC config page on the control network, rather than the printer config page.  Printer config page is accessible when control network unplugged.

How can I force the printer configuration through the Business Network NIC?

Comment: Check your routes, set the correct default routes and a route for your printer to the business network. BTW, using different IP ranges (e.g. 192.168.1.*/24 and 192.168.2.*/24) makes that a lot easier. Talk to whoever administrates those networks.

Comment: What are the subnet masks for each network?  You have overlapping IP ranges if it's the default /24 subnet mask.

Comment: 255.255.255.0 - just the default.  The networks are not normally connected - and they are administered by different outside organizations.  I install systems that allow the 'business' side to get valuable information from the 'control' side that before was available.  This is the first time I have ran into both business and control on the same ip range....  Only one (business) has a default gateway - if that helps...

Comment: Try changing the subnet on both to 255.255.255.128. That will effectively mark anything from .1.0 to .1.127 as one network, and .1.128 to .1.255 as the second network. Then (assuming you can) switch the two IP's you're using, so the business nic is on .75 and the control network is .173. Then your business nic and the printer will be seen as on the same network on your computer. Definitely not elegant, and it won't work if anything on the business network you need access to is on an IP above .127, or anything on the control network below .128.